# How can I use two set of Donkey Konga drums with Taiko No Tatsujin?

Tags: nintendo-switch

Taiko No Tatsujin works with the Donkey Konga drum on Nintendo Switch using a GameCube controller adapter. I managed to get this working in single player by pairing only the Joycons so I could navigate the menu, then once the game had started I switch to `Change Grip/Order`, paired the drum first and then the Joycons, then used the Joycons to navigate the Switch menu back to the game. The drum then worked as player 1.

I am now trying to use a second set of Kongas to play two player, but this seems fraught with problems. Here's what I've tried:

1. Pairing the two drums as players one and two, and the Joycons as player 3. But when the game starts, it changes the Joycons to player 2 (the lights on the Joycons change from two to three) so the Joycons are then player two instead of the drum.
2. Allowing the Joycons to change to player 2, and then once in the game using `Change Grip/Order` to change player 2 back to the drum. The game seems to realise this has happened, however, and drops you back to the main menu. The Joycons (now on player 3) will then refuse to operate the menu.
3. Pair the drums as players 1 and 2, and a GameCube pad as player 3. However, the GameCube pad is then unable to operate the menus.
4. Pair a set of drums as player 1 and a GameCube pad as player 2. Same problem as with (3).
5. Pair a GameCube pad as player 1 and a set of drums as player 2. Operate the menus with the GameCube pad. I can then get as far as the screen where the players select the control method. You can't do this with the drums, so I selected the control method for player one using the GameCube pad. I then tried hot swapping the controllers to see if I could change player two's control method, and then hot swap to the second set of drums. But as soon as I hotplugged the controllers, the game acted as though I had selected the control method, and then started freaking out as though buttons were being held.

So, to summarise: my question is, **how can I use two sets of Donkey Konga drums in Taiko No Tatsujin using a GameCube controller adapter?**